# How to differentiate click event of the recyclerview itself with it's viewholders

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Currently I have a recycler view with match parents width and grid layout inside a section. So I set click listener for the parent layout, and for the list item which both would gives different reaction when clicked. The problem is the list is not always full, and when it is not full, I can't click the white space of the recycler view because it was blocked by the recycler view.

I have tried set click listener to the recycler view itself, but no luck with that. I also can't change the layout params to become wrap content, because it has to be match parent to be put with grid layout.

Actually I have a dirty solution for this, on the getItemCount, I will hardcode the count to be max grid column size, and create an empty layout viewholder type. In the onBindViewholder, I can validate if the current column position bigger than the real list size, I simply lay out that empty layout viewholder which I can set click listener on. I'm just thinking maybe there is a cleaner solution for this.

[image]

Comment: you can set the **itemView.setOnClickListner** to differentiate the click

Comment: yes sir, actually I've thought of that, but the getItemCount() itself should return the real count of the item in the list. To implement click listener on the itemView for this case, I thing I have to override the getItemCount() return the num of max column, and create empty layout as the second type of viewholder. Am I understanding you suggestion correctly?

Comment: If possible please share the XML or view hierarchy diagram; Is the GridLayout inside RecyclerView or RecyclerView is wrapped inside RecyclerView.

Comment: sorry, edited the question

Comment: So you want to enable click events for its child layouts as well? I have done this type of concept.

Comment: What i want would be when I click the child, it will trigger method a(), but when I click everything else, it would trigger method b() sir.

Answer (score 0):

Set onClickListener on the Layout inside, not on the RecyclerView itself.

Add the layout in your custom layout resource file, give it an id and set onClickListener in your adapter class.

Comment: yes, the plan was that, sorry it is because my question is not very clear, so actually I don't need to click listener on the recycler view. What I want is the layout under's click listener to not be blocked by the recycler view. But since I must make the recycler view's width match parent, somehow it blocked the click action even when the grid list item child is not full.

Answer (score 0):

Since the RecyclerView extends Scroll-layout it will override the click settings of the outer layer.

I would say use a constraintlayout and then below the recyclerview add a empty relativelayout covering your gird which can have this click listener;

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view_outer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/global_dimen_16_dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/global_dimen_16_dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/global_dimen_24_dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/global_dimen_16_dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/black12"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/global_dimen_4_dp"
    app:cardElevation="3dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view_inner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white100"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/global_dimen_4_dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp">

       <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"/>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layover"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/recyclerView" />
          </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Just saw your question update; the above XML is for vertical layout.. but on similar lines you can have it for horizontal layout to handle your empty space differently.

Comment: Thank you for you advice, sorry it's not working. Maybe because I have to set my recycler's width to match parent, or 0dp with width constraints to the parent.

Comment: @user3576118 the RecyclerView Adapter's ViewHolder would have click listener to your function a(); while the extra empty layer you will register another clicklistener to function b(); also in your question you've horizontal scroll; and each row can have multiple cards in that case how can you have it to match width ?? Is the UI horizontal or vertical ?